# gtable: Put a black line around all cells in the table body

Tags: r, gridextra, r-grid, gtable

I'm trying to put a relatively heavy line (say lwd = 2 size) around the body of a table using `gridExtra`.  Here's a MWE slightly modified from this documentation [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html).  `gtable` is doing the work under the hood but the documentation for `gtable` is thin; looking at the code didn't help much.

```
g <- tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:3], rows = NULL)
separators <- replicate(1, 
    segmentsGrob(x1 = unit(0,"npc")), 
    simplify=FALSE)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, grobs = separators, 
    t = 1, b = nrow(g), l = 1)
g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, grobs = separators, 
    t = 1, b = nrow(g), r = 3) # error: no default for l
grid.draw(g)
```

I'm trying to get an effect like this (different data):

[image: sample]

The 2nd call to `gtable::gtable_add_grob` gives an error, so obviously my simple notion that `r = 3` will put the line on the right of the 3rd column is naive.  Any suggestions as to how to get a heavier line around the body of the table?  If I can grok the idea for the left and right edges I assume the top and bottom lines can be drawn analogously.

Side note: `gridExtra` was recently revised to use `gtable`.  Previously I had made graphics like the one above with commands similar to those below; I'd like to get pretty close to the same settings if possible (the new method has rows alternating in grey level, that's nicer; I'm really after the old `show.box` feature).

```
myt <- gridExtra::tableGrob(aov1, show.box = TRUE,
                show.rownames = TRUE, show.colnames = TRUE,
                show.csep = TRUE, show.rsep = TRUE,
                separator = "black", gp = grid::gpar(cex = table[3]))
```

Comment: if you look at the function definition, `function (x, grobs, t, l, b = t, r = l`, it explains the error message: `t` and `l` are always required (no default values).

Comment: @baptiste I saw that, but I couldn't figure out the meaning of `l` and `r` in the context of a line dividing the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a rectGrob spanning all the cells you want caged,

```
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
g <- tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:3])
g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, 
                             grobs = rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=NA, 
                                                      lwd=2)), 
                             t = 2, b = nrow(g), l = 2, r = ncol(g))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in words the interpretation of `t = 2`?  The top of the rectangle is at the bottom of the first row, or the top of the 2nd row.  If "top of the 2nd row" is the correct way to look at it, then why would `b = nrow(g)` draw a line at the bottom of the last row?  That's what I don't get about the position arguments in this function.

Comment: tlrb refer to the index position in the gtable (think of it as a matrix): `t=2, b=5` means that the grob will be placed from the second to the fifth row (inclusive), and by default `rectGrob()` expands to take the space of the full viewport.

Comment: BTW it becomes trickier with lines (the separator example) because segments can be placed on either edge of a given cell (top/bottom or anywhere in-between). But rectangles are easy.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.  For completeness, what's the logic when adding just a line, as in my original example?

Comment: OTOH you can add it to the top of each cell starting from the second row with y=1 in the segment grob, or to the bottom of each cell starting from the first row with y=0 in the segments grob. Does the separator example in the vignette make sense? (to be honest I usually do it with trial and error)

Comment: feel free to send a pull request with improved doc/vignette example, I'm aware it's pretty minimal

Comment: That example does make sense, to a degree.  When I tried to add to the right side of the right most column I could never get it quite right.  Anyway, I'm back in business.  Thanks so much.